# Swollen leg of red ear slider turtle

Tags: turtles

Recently I came up with one of the red ear slider turtle that has its one of the legs swallowned up . It is so worse that he is suppose to keep the leg out of the shell. Is there any treatment I can provide to him. My vet says its case of ganagarin and there is no treatment for it.

Answer (score 2):

The most common treatment for gangrene is surgery to remove injured tissue. Generally this is by amputation of the leg. It is followed up with antibiotics and normal post surgery treatments.

If the gangrene  has traveled into the body, it is usually fatal.

If you vet is saying

> its case of ganagarin and there is no treatment for it.

I assume this means that it is past the point were amputation might be effective.

Getting a second opinion, from a different vet is probably a good idea. If the second vets says the same you may want to discuss [euthanasia](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euthanasia) options with the vet.